# Knockout.js foreach binding works, but with binding does not

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js, single-page-application, knockout-3.0

Using Knockout.js 3.2.0, I've been fighting to get an ***observableArray*** successfully bound, and have narrowed it down to the ***with*** binding. ***Foreach*** has no problems, but ***with*** throws the error *Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "with: function (){return contactLists }".*

Can anyone help me understand what's going on?

This works:

```
<!-- ko foreach: contactLists -->
    <p data-bind="text: title"></p>
<!-- /ko -->
```

This doesn't:

```
<!-- ko with: contactLists -->
    <p data-bind="text: title"></p>
<!-- /ko -->
```

***ko.observableArray*** and ***applyBindings*** declarations:

```
var viewModels = {
        contactLists: ko.observableArray([new ContactList({title: "This Is List #1", subCount: 4321}), new ContactList({title: "List #2", subCount: 9876}), new ContactList({title: "jList #3", subCount: 1234})])
    }

    ko.applyBindings(viewModels);
```

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "with" binding doesn't work with arrays. You have to specify the element to work. Example:

```
<!-- ko foreach: contactLists -->
  <!-- ko with: data -->
    <p data-bind="text: gender"> </p> 
  <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->


function ContactList(data) {
  this.title = data.title;
  this.subCount = data.subCount;
}

var viewModels = {
  contactLists: ko.observableArray([
    {title: "This Is List #1", data: { subCount: 4321, gender: "male"}},
    {title: "List #2", data: { subCount: 5321, gender: "female"}},
    {title: "jList #3", data: { subCount: 1221, gender: "any"}}])
}

ko.applyBindings(viewModels);
```

[See the Pen](http://codepen.io/sbaglieri/pen/vEKaeP/)

Comment: With your advice I was able to get it to work. I can't believe I missed that. Nice catch!